# Debug in Playground or Tricky Way?

Tags: swift, xcode

As i know there is no debug in Playground. But for example, i wonder how i can observe some events in Playground ? I wonder when observer property set ? Only options print statements ?

Answer (score 0):

> Only options print statements?

Basically, yes. Just one of many reasons why playgrounds are the work of the devil and you shouldn't use them. (But then, you have to ask yourself how you would do the same thing in an actual project — probably, the same way, with a print statement.)